# Copy current path to clipboard or select address bar in Total Commander

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, total-commander

Is there any shortcut to copy the path of the current directory in Total Commander?

Also, is it possible to select or highlight the address bar with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can indeed copy the path of any file or folder you are viewing in any of the panes.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will add the current directory path to the address bar.

You can also get individual files' paths. Select the files you want to get the path from, click

> Mark > Copy Names With Path To Clipboard.

You can even add a new button to the toolbar which activates this command if you use this function very often. Add a new button to the toolbar, and assign it this command: `cm_CopyFullNamesToClip`

Another option for easy access is to map a custom keyboard shortcut to this function. This is done in

> Configuration > Misc.

As for a shortcut to focus on the command line, there is no built in shortcut to do it, but you can again assign a new button or keyboard shortcut to the command `cm_FocusCmdLine`, which takes you from wherever you are straight to the command bar, selecting its whole content.

Comment: In case you want to copy (for mapped network drives) the UNC path (\\server\..\file) instead of the local path (Z:\...\file), you can use the command cm_CopyNetNamesToClip instead. For all other paths it works identically.

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>Home</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

As molgar / randy-skretka said, and also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> but use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to go to command line and cut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

because that also works in *Brief* and *Thumbnail View* 'mode', not only in *Full* (extra: see available modes with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks, I like Shift + F6 a bit more ;-)

Answer (score 11):

> Is there any shortcut to copy the path of the current directory in
>   Total Commander?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then <kbd>←</kbd> OR <kbd>→</kbd> (arrow keys) to copy the current directory to the command line and then select it for you. Then just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy.

> Also, is it possible to select or highlight the address bar with a
>   keyboard shortcut?

Use your <kbd>Home</kbd> key to put you over the **[..]** notation at the top of the directory listing. That's the parent directory. Then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to focus on and highlight the address bar (edit it if you need to!).

Comment: in TC 8+ it's `shift+F6` for me, **not** `ctrl+f6`. edited the answer since I accidentally entered the *'directotry bar'* / *'breadcrumb bar'* / *'current directory above the file lists'* by accident and was looking for the shortcut

Comment: the `←` OR `→` won't work in all situations. Consider thumbnail mode or `Ctrl+F1` *'Brief'* mode. use `Shift`+`→` instead

Answer (score 9):

A good hack is using:
Configuration>Options>Misc>Redefine hotkeys.
Now you can add Control + L
and in Command select cm_EditPath

pressing Control+L will select the path just like Firefox, Explore (in windows 8), Dolphin, Nautilus, ...

Comment: And it work for me to copy directory current path also :)

Comment: Also look [here](https://chodounsky.net/2013/08/02/access-total-commander-path-with-shortcut/).

Answer (score 8):

Configuration -> Options -> Misc. -> Redefine hotkeys -> Hotkey -> Assign a desired hotkey (e.g F10) -> Command cm_CopySrcPathToClip

This is what the configuration menu looks like:

[image: URL for the image of the configuration menu]

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little to explain how to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: if you need a full file path with file name in it then use cm_CopyFullNamesToClip.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are keyboard shortcuts to either of the functions.

A list of TC hotkeys can be found here:
http://www.keyxl.com/aaa8055/84/Total-Commander-keyboard-shortcuts.htm

There is a way to create custom hotkeys for functions in TC (for all available commands) or even for custom commands. Information can be found [here](http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=18298) and [here](http://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php/Internal_command). You may be able to create your desired shortcuts there.

Answer (score 0):

What about a **1-click solution**? It's using Python (which is great for so many reasons):

1. *[ If you don't have it yet ]:* Install Python from https://www.python.org/downloads/ (in general the latest version before 3.0 is generally recommended, it has greater support, but in this case it shouldn't matter).
2. *[ If you don't have it yet ]:* In command line type: `pip install pyperclip`.
3. Write the following short script and save it as a `.pyw` file:

   ```
   '''
       Run from TC's button with a "%P parameter (not "%p)
       It will pass the current path into the clipboard
   '''
   import sys, pyperclip

   pyperclip.copy(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
   ```
4. Drag the script onto your TC's button bar. It will become a button.
5. Right-click on the newly created button and in the "Parameters" field type `"%P` (not `"%p`; the single double-quotation mark `"` is important to handle paths with more than one space character next to each other).
6. *[ Optional ]:* Change it's icon by typing `wcmicons.dll` in the "Icon file" field, and select something intuitive, like: [image]

From now on, whenever you click on that button, the full path to your current panel's directory will be copied into the clipboard!

Answer (score 0):

I think <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> is what you wanted, then you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the path.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually TC allows to edit current path if you press Shift+F6 on ".." item. But you may assign any hotkey under Configuration - Misc. for internal command cm_EditPath and use it for this task - it will work always. E.g. I like to use Alt+Up hotkey.

Source: [Shortcut to the path area (current directory) ? (solved)](http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=215553)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, but seems that Ctr+Shift+Enter put selected file path and name into TC command, then left arrow select whole string and Ctr+X cut it from TC command int Clipboard.
Maybe it will be helpful to someone

Answer (score -1):

A solution with bat instead of python:

1. go to "configuration/Misc/redefine hotkeys"
2. chose a free key combination
3. press the magnifying glass button
4. press the new button to define a new user command
5. in the command write: `cmd /c echo`
6. in the parameters: `%P | clip`
7. click on "OK" twice, then press the green checkbox

Comment: Technically its not wrong, but its kind of a long stretch.

Answer (score -1):

CNTRL-P is correct, but to have the current path in the command-area on the bottom, there is CNTRL-SHIFT-ENTER